# Cryptojs и PHP не совместимы или мне это кажется

Tags: php, node.js, md5, ascii, cryptojs

Есть две реализации одного и того же, на PHP:

```
<?php

$digest = "�X]x�C�����";
$password = "123456";

$ctx = hash_init('md5');
hash_update($ctx, $digest);
hash_update($ctx, $password);
$hash = hash_final($ctx, true);

echo $hash;
```

и с помощью Cryptojs для Node:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

var digest = "�X]x�C�����";
var password = "123456";

var ctx = crypto.createHash('md5');
ctx.update(digest);
ctx.update(password);
var hash = ctx.digest();

console.log(hash.toString());
```

Вот только возвращают они разные результаты, PHP:

```
���|�r�c;����   #�
```

а Node:

```
���|�r�c;���  #�
```

Как заставить JS код возвращать то же самое, что и PHP?

Comment: Начать с того, что php вы просите вернуть бинарные данные, а в ноде ascii. Да и digest похоже разный

Comment: К тому де сравнивать вопросительные знаки на глаз в вашем вопросе, занятие так себе

Comment: Ага, спасибо. Вы похоже навели меня на правильные мысли:

var hash = ctx.digest();
console.log(hash.toString());

В этом случае "вопросительные знаки на глаз" выглядят уже более похожими, но все равно не то: ���|�r�c;��� #�

Comment: Лучше уж оба в hex вывести

Comment: Так увы не получится. Данные нужно отправлять именно в таком виде, в каком это делает PHP код.

Comment: Я не предлагаю так и оставить. Я предлагаю сделать этот эксперимент и убедиться что результат одинаковый. Если не одинаковый, значит на входе разные данные. Потому что md5 все считают одинаково, иначе в нём не было бы смысла.